# Questions about Random Effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, random-effects-model

So I ran two linear regression models, one with a random effect and another without a random effect. I had compared the two models with the `anova()` function in program R. I have attached the results below.

My question is should I continue with the mixed-effect model even if the model without random effects fits better, or should I continue with the model without the random effects. Should I still try to account for the random effect in my future models, if it doesn't seem to fit better?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Which of the models is the mixed model?

Comment: M3 is the mixed model

Comment: what is your goal in doing the modeling? (Broadly speaking, prediction or inference?)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not consider enough information to give a proper response. How many observations do you have per cluster and how many clusters? Does the multilevel structure make sense from the literature or for the specific context of your problem?

It is hard to properly gauge the relevance of your output as it consists of relative measures (i.e. what if both models are a bad fit?). You could compute the **intra-class correlation** coefficient in order to have a descriptive look at the structure of your data. As a rule of thumb, some suggest using mixed models if at least 10% of the variability is explained by the higher hierarchy or level.

Overall, I would say that the risks of misspecification from not including random effects are much larger than the loss of power from being overly cautious, so if your data structure suggests it I would choose the mixed-effects model.